# Error APT2259: '50%' is incompatible with attribute height (attr) dimension

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, splash-screen, layer-list

I receive this error when I try to specify a percentage on my **splash-screen.xml**:

> error APT2259: '50%' is incompatible with attribute height (attr)
> dimension.

I want the screen to be splitted by two colors. My code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:height="50%" android:gravity="fill_horizontal|top">
    <color android:color="@color/yellow"/>
  </item>
  
  <item android:height="50%" android:gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom">
    <color android:color="@color/red"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

How could I achieve this? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In android is not posible to specify a percentage (%) as a value. You have to specify a value in `sp`.

Take a look at the Dimensions documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: this is not true. this works very well:

<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:drawable="...."

    android:insetLeft="20%"
    android:insetRight="20%"
    android:insetTop="20%"
    android:insetBottom="20%"
    />